# What is the built-in PHP function for "compressing" or "defragmenting" an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I know it'd be trivial to code myself, but in the interest of not having more code to maintain if it's built in to PHP already, is there a built-in function for "compressing" a PHP array?  In other words, let's say I create an array thus:

```
$array = array();
$array[2000] = 5;
$array[3000] = 7;
$array[3500] = 9;
```

What I want is an array where $array[0] == 5, $array[1] == 7, $array[2] == 9.

I could do this:

```
function array_defragment($array) {
    $squashed_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $squashed_array[] = $item;
    }
    return $squashed_array;
}
```

...but it seems like the kind of thing that would be built in to PHP - I just can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use [`array_values`](http://docs.php.net/array_values):

```
$array = array();
$array[2000] = 5;
$array[3000] = 7;
$array[3500] = 9;

$array = array_values($array);
var_dump($array === array(5, 7, 9));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Still useful 10 years in the future!

Answer (score 0):

A newer method is the spread operator `...`

```
$arr = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'];

unset($arr[2]);

$arr = [...$arr];

print_r($arr);
```

Gives me a result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => orange
    [2] => green
)
```

However, do keep in mind, the spread operator `...` is significantly slower as a proportion in comparison to `array_values`. You may run the following test:

```
<?php
function getTimeNow()
{
    return microtime(true) * 1000;
}

$arr1 = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $arr1[$i + rand(0,4)] = $i;
}

$start = getTimeNow();
$spreadTest = [...$arr1];
echo "\nTime taken for spread: " . getTimeNow() - $start;

$start = getTimeNow();
$arrayValues = array_values($arr1);
echo "\nTime taken for array_values: " . getTimeNow() - $start;
```

Results are:

```
$ php index.php

Time taken for spread: 0.8779296875
Time taken for array_values: 0.4228515625
```