# Compress a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to take an array that looks something like ...

```
array( 11 => "fistVal", 19 => "secondVal", 120=> "thirdVal", 200 =>"fourthVal");
```

and convert it to...

```
array( 0 => "fistVal", 1 => "secondVal", 2=> "thirdVal", 3 =>"fourthVal");
```

This is what I came up with -

```
function compressArray($array){
    if(count($array){
        $counter = 0;
        $compressedArray = array();
        foreach($array as $cur){
            $compressedArray[$count] = $cur;
            $count++;   
        }
        return $compressedArray;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm just curious if there is any built-in functionality in php or neat tricks to do this.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111761/what-is-the-built-in-php-function-for-compressing-or-defragmenting-an-array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`array_values`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Example taken directly from the link,

```
<?php
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to get an array of the values:

```
$input = array( 11 => "fistVal", 19 => "secondVal", 120=> "thirdVal", 200 =>"fourthVal");
$expectedOutput = array( 0 => "fistVal", 1 => "secondVal", 2=> "thirdVal", 3 =>"fourthVal");
var_dump(array_values($input) === $expectedOutput);  // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

array_values() is probably the best choice, but as an interesting side-note, array_merge and array_splice will also re-index an array.

```
$input = array( 11 => "fistVal", 19 => "secondVal", 120=> "thirdVal", 200 =>"fourthVal");
$reindexed = array_merge($input);
//OR
$reindexed = array_splice($input,0); //note: empties $input
//OR, if you do't want to reassign to a new variable:
array_splice($input,count($input)); //reindexes $input
```